# deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: not working

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to delete nicely the cells of mu UITableView :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [self deleteModelForIndexPath:indexPath];

        [mainTableView beginUpdates];
        [mainTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [mainTableView endUpdates];

    }
}
```

This throws the following exception :

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (2) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (3), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'
```

I don't get the `(0 inserted, 0 deleted)` part. Why wouldn't it work ?

Thanks

Comment: Seems to be that problem is in [self deleteModelForIndexPath:indexPath]; Are you sure that model is deleted from dataSource?

Comment: Can you share the code for `[self deleteModelForIndexPath:indexPath]`?

Comment: If I do 'NSLog(@"%@", @([model count]));' before and after '[self deleteModelForIndexPath:indexPath];', it prints x and x-1 ... It's a really complicated method so I guess it would be more confusing then anything ! :p

Comment: The other thing to check then, is to check your `numberOfRowsInSection` method to make sure it's returning the right thing before and after.

Answer (score 1):

You should update the table data at the same time. If you are using an array object for each row, remove the deleted one from the array.

Answer (score 1):

The error means what it says:

> The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (2) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (3), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'

This is probably one of the better error messages out there and it basically means that the amount data backing your table view is out of sync with it's state in the UI, specifically the number of sections (hint: check `–numberOfSectionsInTableView:`) before/after your delete. If you delete a row/section from the table, you need to make sure you delete that row/section from the data backing the table.

> (0 inserted, 0 deleted)

Means that the API didn't find that your data source had any deleted sections.

Are you absolutely certain that is doing what you think it is doing:

```
[self deleteModelForIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` methods for such an operation. You should simply do:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{
        [self deleteModelForIndexPath:indexPath];

        [mainTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }
}
```

Also you can take a look at the documentation about `beginUpdates`:

> Call this method if you want subsequent insertions, deletion, and
>   selection operations (for example, `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and
>   `indexPathsForVisibleRows`) to be animated simultaneously. This group of
>   methods must conclude with an invocation of endUpdates. These method
>   pairs can be nested. If you do not make the insertion, deletion, and
>   selection calls inside this block, table attributes such as row count
>   might become invalid. You **SHOULD NOT** call `reloadData` within the group;
>   if you call this method within the group, you will need to perform any
>   animations yourself.

Comment: While you're technically correct in that the begin/endUpdates bracketing isn't necessary, it also isn't going to change anything in this case.